# Symfony 2.5 and Angular $http

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I have some problem when I'm using $http with my API that I've written using Symfony. When I'm using $http.get at server side I'm adding a header to response  : Access-Control-Allow-Origin and everything works and I can get required data from server. But when I'm using $http.post and adding this header , nothing works.

```
$http.post('http://myhost.loc/posts', {data:'Test string'}).success(function(data, status){
    console.log(data);
}).error(function(data, status){
    console.log(status);
});
```

And I get an error :
OPTIONS http://myhost.loc/posts  and
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending a cross domain request, there is a preflight request sent with the OPTIONS method.
The purpose of that preflight request is to check if the ressource is reachable

You can try that in your apache .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Should I add into my host that works with static files or that works with API?

Comment: I added this lines into my htaccess file tried different combinations and it still not works. It gonna kill me)

Comment: Instead of POST request it sends OPTIONS request. I made a2enmod headers, allowmethods for my Apache and I'm getting new error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.host.loc/app_dev.php/add. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: is everything ok on the sf side? Your action allow the right method?

Answer (score 2):

its a CORS problem first of all enable CORS on your angular app by

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

A server supporting CORS must respond to requests with several access control headers:

```
• Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Comment: I made it but I didn't help. I still have the same problem.

Comment: did your server responding with that header which I mentioned ?

Comment: In my action that sends response I have following code 
$response = new JsonResponse();

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

        return $response;

Comment: try to debug   the request   with chrome network and make sure what you sending without the X-Requested-With and your server responding with Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Comment: I don't know why bu in Request I have this
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
And response returns
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST

Comment: I guess from some reasons this code doesn't work
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');